# Set Jenkins build name only on successful build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to set the build name of a Jenkins build only on a successful build.  Any failure, whether in building or testing, should use the 'default' (build number) instead.

I can't find any mention of this in the documentation or online. Is this possible?

Comment: This depends heavily on what kind of Jenkins job do you use: Pipeline or Freestyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple to do with Groovy Postbuild: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

You have some nice examples there too. So just check result and then set the:

```
manager.build.result
```

As they do in Example 3

Answer (score 1):

In the post build operation you can run a "[set of scripts](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PostBuildScript+Plugin)" - there you can select any way to do so, set a description, run system groovy or groovy script to change the name or any other method of your choosing - you can add many build steps to help you do so. wrap it around a [conditional statement](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) and run it only when build is successful.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this.  Between this and @MaTePe's answer I think I have an approach that will work for me.